# how do I access the vector value std :: vector <cv :: Point2f> pto

Tags: c++, opencv, std, stdvector

How do I access the vector value

`std :: vector <cv :: Point2f> pto`

into a separate vector x and y

```
std :: vector <float> x;
```

already tried several ways:

```
x (i) = pto.at <cv :: float> (i) .pt.x
```

but did not work

Comment: Please edit your post to give us more context about the problem. Most people wouldn't have known this was about OpenCV unless they looked at the tags.

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to extract X and Y values separately from an array like your own, I did it like this:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
//stuff

cornersSize = corners.size();
for(int k=0; k<cornersSize; k++){          //goes through all cv::Point2f in the vector
                float x = corners[k].x;   //first value
                float y = corners[k].y;   //second value
                //stuff
}
```

The docs had everything - http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

Answer (score 0):

You access the values in an `std::vector` with either [`at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) or [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/):

```
std :: vector <float> x (n); // Initializes `x` to hold `n` values.
x.at (i) = pto.at (i) .x;
```

This will assign the `x` component of the `Point2f` at index `i` in `pto` to index `i` in the `x` vector.